# What could be a reason for storing numeric values as varchar?

Tags: sql-server

Just stumbled upon a table at work where numeric values ($ amounts, to be specific) are stored as VARCHAR. I asked the developers why and they said it's designed that way to function in line with architectural processes.

I just started learning databases and don't know any technical intricacies yet but I also have been working with SQL for a few years now and cannot think of any reasons why it would be done that way. I'm having to convert those numbers in queries before doing any math calculations with them. Any experts here who could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you not go back and ask what those "architectural processes" are? To me it sounds like "someone cooked up a script to import this data from Excel/CSV and nobody could be bothered to figure out how to make the import typed, so we just pour everything in there as strings and convert it later", or something along those lines. Such things need not have *good* reasons, but what the actual reasons *are* only the authors can tell you.

Comment: There is no practical reason you would need to store numbers as strings. In fact, all this really does is make them take up more space and make it harder to perform arithmetic or comparisons on them. If they do that so it "functions in line with architectural processes", then it's likely just a bandaid so they don't have to fix or re-write these poorly written processes.

Comment: The only reasoning I can think of -- and, let me be clear, it's not sound reasoning at all! -- would be if someone thought, "hey, if we store them as (formatted) strings, we won't have to format them on the display side!"  This would make more sense (but still be _very_ flawed and short-sighted) if the amounts were in different currencies with different display formats and numbers of decimal places.

Comment: It's possible that the originators never thought anybody would ever have to treat the data in this particular database as numeric -- never have to sum it, never have to query it. Short-sighted, again.

Comment: I don't normally give anything resembling career advice, but I'd find out -- politely, and inoffensively, and not in a tone of suspicion -- whether other databases there were designed using the same guidelines, and whether they plan to keep those "architectural processes" and standards. Because this is such a basic thing to have got wrong and not fix, that I wonder what other things they're doing wrong, and whether you'll be learning the right things and not spinning your wheels compensating for 'set in stone' bad decisions, if you stay there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert We have some real grumpy folks and any innocuous question get them all worked up there so I prefer not to

Comment: @AnnL. yeah, the folks there are very grumpy and know-it-all so I get no pleasure in asking them anything. Even asking my original question was a big event.

Comment: Then I suggest filing this away in the "that's just how they work here" part of your brain, and also tickle the "let's not forget to keep my resume up to date and look out for jobs with people who act like professionals at every opportunity and can explain sub-optimal choices without getting annoyed, rather than grizzled veterans with entitlement, no matter how much they may have done to earn their spurs" part of said brain. Even if that goes a bit beyond the scope of your question. :P I, for one, am always delighted if the newbies ask the tough questions, since I get to revisit things.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I guess that is a sensible way to process it. But it got me so confused that I ordered a book on MS SQL Server 2019 to learn more about these "architectural processes"  lol

Comment: If it's a good book, it will probably advise you to use the appropriate data types for the data, and also why storing numeric data as `VARCHAR` is almost always a bad idea. The discussion should usually be on why monetary values should be stored using `DECIMAL`, and not (say) `FLOAT`. `VARCHAR` is right out and really only appropriate as a starting point in an ETL flow.

Comment: One of the core reasons to store data in a relational database is to ensure data integrity. Proper data types along with constraints help ensure validity. A database can be used as nothing more than a storage engine but that's not a good architectural practice.

Comment: You are asking good questions that probably should have been asked and addressed long ago. Keep up the good work. the company might do well to fast-track you to a technical lead position.